# Updating information in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a filtered dataset, `new_df`, like this

```
    Label  New_Label    Username    Look_up
59  1.0    True         vald21      val
67  1.0    True         2512        2512
75  1.0    True         Christine   Chris
```

which was created to assign a new label (`New_Label`) when some conditions were met. I have also another dataset (`df`) which includes all the data (this dataset is where the data above where extract from) but has not information about the `New_Label` (as the dataset above was created for this reason, by filtering based on specific conditions).

```
        Label   Username    Look_up
    59  1.0     vald21      val
    67  1.0     2512        2512
    67  0.0     faehr6542   faehr
...
    75  1.0     Christine   Chris
   122  0.0     starogm     starogm
```

I would like to change the `Label` from my original dataset `df` to those rows in `new_df`, when it is the case Label and New_Label do not match.

```
        Label   Username    Look_up
    59  0       vald21      val
    67  0       2512        2512
    67  0       faehr6542   faehr
...
    75  0       Christine   Chris
   122  0     starogm     starogm
```

where `True` in `new_df` corresponds to `0` and `False` to `1` in `Label` column. I do not want to change the other values, only those ones in the `new_df` dataset (my key would be Username).

Could you explain me, please, how to change information in the original dataset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try merging two dataframe and then using `.assign` along with `np.where`. When merging with `outer`, the values not present will have `NA` so `np.where` with `notnull()` can be used:

```
pd.merge(df, new_df, how='outer').assign(Label = lambda row:np.where(row['New_Label'].notnull(), 0, 1))
```

If you do not want `New_Label`, you can drop the column with `.drop('New_Label', axis=1)`. Something like below (if written in one line):

```
pd.merge(df, new_df, how='outer').assign( Label = lambda row:  np.where(row['New_Label'].notnull(), 0, 1)).drop('New_Label', axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, @student. Unfortunately I am getting this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. It might be because one is as float number and another one is as string, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: can you break the code and see which section is causing error? I mean: `pd.merge(df, new_df, how='outer')` then `.assign(Label = lambda row:np.where(row['New_Label'].notnull(), 0, 1))` It looked fine with example above.

Comment: Not sure, why it wouldnot allow to merge? Works fine for the above sample. May be you can update question or else someone else may find better solution

Comment: I found the issue: it was due to a missing 'on' in merging. However I have got a new error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'where'`

Comment: ok, I assumed it would merge in index when `on` is not specified. Can you see what is the result look like after `merge` i.e. removing all piece of code after that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to flip `'New_Label'`, convert it to int and assign it to `'Label'`:

```
new_df['Label'] = (new_df['New_Label']==False).astype(int)
```

Comment: Hi @SHINJI.K. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is not what I have been looking for. Sorry about this. What I am looking for is to merge information from new_df and df, changing values of Label only for those observations which are in new_df (so without changing the other labels). In new_df True value corresponds to 0 in df, while false to 1 (in new_df all observations should have value True, as it is a filtered dataset). So I would need to change to 0 all the corresponding observations in df.