# 'list' object has no attribute 'where' trying to merge two datasets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to merge two datasets (df and new_df) getting information from one (New_Label) to another one (Label).

The first dataset, df, includes all the columns and data:

```
    Label   Username    Look_up   (Other columns ...)
59  1.0     vald21      val
67  1.0     2512        2512
67  0.0     faehr6542   faehr
```

...
75  1.0     Christine   Chris
122  0.0     starogm     starogm

while `new_df` comes from `df` by filtering rows which include some specific words:

```
    Label  New_Label    Username    Look_up
59  1.0    True         vald21      val
67  1.0    True         2512        2512
75  1.0    True         Christine   Chris
```

I would like to replace the old values in `Label` in df with the new ones in `new_df` (under `New_Label` column): `True` should correspond to `0` and `False` to `1`. Since `new_df` is a filtered dataset, all the values in the dataset, under `New_Label` column, have value `True` (i.e. `0` in `Label`).

Following the suggestion a user gave me here ([Updating information in dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660918/updating-information-in-dataframe-column)), I have applied the following:

```
df2=pd.merge(df, new_df[['Username','New_Label']], on='Username', how='outer').assign(Label = lambda row:np.where(row['New_Label'].notnull(), 0, 1))
```

but I have got this error:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in assign(self, **kwargs)
   3565 
   3566         for k, v in kwargs.items():
-> 3567             data[k] = com.apply_if_callable(v, data)
   3568         return data
   3569 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py in apply_if_callable(maybe_callable, obj, **kwargs)
    341 
    342     if callable(maybe_callable):
--> 343         return maybe_callable(obj, **kwargs)
    344 
    345     return maybe_callable

<ipython-input-233-fd59bc42a769> in <lambda>(row)
----> 1 df2=pd.merge(df, new_df[['Username','New_Label']], on='Username', how='outer').assign(Label = lambda row:np.where(row['New_Label'].notnull(), 0, 1))

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'where'
```

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: looks like you assigned `np` to a list somewhere in your code

Comment: New_Label1 contain list

Comment: Thank you so much to both. Is there any way to avoid this thing? the list was used for determining the new dataset (I had a list of usernames and if they contained specific words I assigned a True value)

Comment: @BEN_YO: New_Label should contain only True or False value (actually only True value since it was filtered in order to have only True values)

Comment: @still_learning can you find the row with list and show that to us ?

Comment: Yes, sure. Can you tell me how to do it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try import `numpy` again

```
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.merge(df, new_df[['Username','New_Label']], on='Username', how='outer')
df2['Label'] = np.where(df2['New_Label'].notnull(), 0, 1))
```

Comment: @still_learning then change New_Label to New_Label_y